# How to change div color when gradient is scrolled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image which has many gradient colors. It is scrolled down in the page. So where the image color stops in the center of the page, there the thumbnail color value is changed. How to do this?

I am not sure so i am posting jsfiddle with only html and css.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/madhu72kumar/6Kkmf/10/)

```
//code
#colors{

    width:123px;
    height:1360px ;
    background-image:url('http://s26.postimg.org/p4x2on37t/bgimage.jpg');
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see any scroll bar on the palette ... or you are asking us to make one?

Comment: no need of scrollbar.

Comment: And how do you expect us to get the color from the image? This would require a canvas and quite a bit of complicated code that you should try to write yourself.

Comment: You know right that you are asking us to make a plugin?

Comment: @adeneo close, and he is expecting us to write a plugin..

Comment: @Mr.Alien : hi Alien, is it difficult to do?

Comment: @AngelGuy yes it is, if you want, check these out.. http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-color-pickers-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should get the color and set it to the thumbnail as you scroll

```
var bg = $('#colors').css('background-image').replace(/(url\(|\)|\")/g,'');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    console.log('loaded')
    var canvas = $('<canvas />').get(0);
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

    $('#wrapper').on('scroll', function() {
        console.log('test')
        var top       = $(this).scrollTop();
        var height    = $(this).outerHeight();
        var x         = (height / 2) + top;
        var pixelData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(10, x, 1, 1).data;
        console.log(pixelData)

        $('#preview').css('background', 'rgb('+pixelData[0]+', '+pixelData[1]+', '+pixelData[2]+')')
    }).trigger('scroll');
}
img.src = bg;
if (img.complete) img.onload();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Kkmf/15/)

Comment: thank u. this is working only in chrome. not working in mozilla and IE. Is it not possible to pick color from background image? and why did u convert jpeg image to some other format. Could u pls explain.

Comment: You can't use an image from another domain in canvas like this due to the same origin policy, so I had to convert the image to Base 64 to make it work in JSFiddle, but if the image is on the same domain in your site you can just use the image, you don't have to use the Base 64.

Comment: It seems the other browsers aren't firing the onload event, try it on your page with the image url and not the base 64, as that seems to be causing the issue.

Comment: @AngelGuy - Actually, it was just a quoting issue, Firefox returns extra quotes around the URL returned from the CSS. For IE it was the wrong jQuery version. Updated the answer to work with those browsers as well.

Comment: @AngelGuy - And you included jQuery, tried adding a document.ready wrapper around the code, checked the console for errors etc?

Comment: Now it's working with base64 in my local folder. Not working with jpg image. have i done any wrong? $(document).ready(function(){ var bg = $('#colors').css('background-image', "url(bgimage1.jpg)"); var img = new Image(); i can see image is loaded in my page but color is not changing along with jpg image. Console is showing error "Failed to load resource." pls help.

Comment: @AngelGuy - The image has to be on the same domain due to the same-origin policy ?

Comment: yes, i am not calling from external location. i am calling from local folder.